# How to setup configuration for SOAP service testing when using WebServiceServerTest, MockWebServiceClient in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap

As question states, I am a bit confused about how to setup **SOAP** service testing in **Java (Spring)**.

In my specific case, I have custom endpoint *interceptors*. I would like to confirm, that there is interaction with them and maybe capture what they are receiving, during test.

At the moment, I can see, that they are missing during testing. I can tell it, because I'm mutating response in actual application, but don't see same/expected result during testing.

I am using `Java 17`, latest `spring-ws-test` and `spring-boot 2.7.6`

**UPD:**
Some references, that I used

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.autoconfigured-webservices.server
- https://jschmitz.dev/posts/how_to_test_the_web_services_of_your_spring_boot_application_with_webservicesservertest/

The problem is, that none of them cover configuration.

On Baeldung, there was one note:

> As mentioned previously, `@WebServiceServerTest` will not load the whole application context. If we do need to load the entire application context for the test, then we should consider using the `@SpringBootTest` combined with the `@AutoConfigureMockWebServiceClient`. We can then use this client in a similar fashion to send the request and verify the response, as shown previously.

But I am wondering if this is the only way to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this setup:

```
@WebServiceServerTest(components = { YourWsInterceptor.class })
@Import({ YourWsConfig.class })
class YourWsServerTest {
    ...
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWs
public class YourWsConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
        ...
    }

}
```